# How to find the sync_guid of an existing internet search engine?

Tags: sharepoint

Actually, i am trying to find the "sync_guid" of several searchs engines like DuckDuckGo, Ask, and several others.

I have find this answer:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26362/how-to-know-the-guid-of-a-database
But i am not familiar with theses cmdlet commands.

And i have found this:
http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/02/find-guid-of-webapp-site-collection-web-list-view-column.html
After having install an Windows Server 2008 R2 and the SharePoint 2010 setup, i try to understand how to get this settings.
At the configuration wizard step, i must enter the "Database server" and the "Database name".
I'm not familiar with SharePoint either, but as far as I understand it's impossible for me to synchronize a database of an external site, right?

If anyone could enlighten me on this.
Thanks.